# libxml2: How to sort xmlNode result in ascending and descending order?

Tags: c, libxml2

Is there a way where I can get xpath result in ascending or descending order, using libxml2 and C ?

Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, this isn't possible with XPath 1.0. You either have to sort the values yourself (using the C library function `qsort`, for example) or you have to use XSLT.